# Phonegap app is not building. Error "oh geez your Build Failed"

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I was able to buid app fine but today I got error, mentioned above in a question. Phonegap is not building the app. I have made no changes in it that may cause the error. It was working fine 2 days before from today. I have added all the stack trace. 
I am new and can't get it.

```
Build Date: 2017-01-23 08:25:36 +0000
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
:CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2510Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72510Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2510Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2510Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2510Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2510Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2510Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132340Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42510Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2510Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase980Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement980Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm980Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid980Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks980Library
:prepareMeLeolinShortcutBadger114Library
:prepareProjectCordovaLibUnspecifiedReleaseLibrary
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:mergeReleaseShaders
:compileReleaseShaders
:generateReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResources/project/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.


/project/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.371 secs
Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/project/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/project/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Comment: Compile SDK version ? Build Tools version ? Probably a mismatch.

Comment: issue has been resolved!!!

Comment: How did you managed to resolve it? Please post the answer so I can learn from it. Thanks!

Comment: you can check my answer. @MagicDragon

Answer (score 0):

There was a old version of phonegap "cli" in app that was causing the build to fail. Once you update your phonegap cli version i.e latest version: cli-6.4.0, one can easily build the app using phonegap if someone face above issue.